# Is it possible to insert art words to an excel？

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to watermark excel.

I've found two methods.The first method is to insert art words to excel as watermark, the second is insert picture as watermark.

I want to implement with the first method, but can't find access to insert art word in apache poi. Is it possible to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to be able to add the watermark programmatically?  If you're going to use a standardized watermark on everything, it might be simplest to generate the image manually and add the image as the watermark, rather than trying to control WordArt.

Here is some help with [WordArt Watermarks via Java](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Locking+WordArt+Watermark).

Comment: There is a problem with the way of adding watermark with pictures, the data in watermarked excel can't be copied, unless the user remove the picture by hand. That's why I want to wartermark excel with WordArt.

Comment: I've never had a problem with copying data from worksheets with watermarks (added with steps like [these options including a text watermark](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-watermark-in-Excel-a372182a-d733-484e-825c-18ddf3edf009#odh_custom)).  That would be a major oversight on Microsoft's end, but perhaps you're referring to copying data from Excel using Java specifically.

Answer (score 0):

[GroupDocs.Watermark for Java](https://products.groupdocs.com/watermark/java) API could be a suitable option for you to add Word Art as watermark in Excel worksheets. This is how you can do it.

```
CellsDocument doc = Document.load(CellsDocument.class, "sample.xlsx");

// Create text watermark
TextWatermark textWatermark = new TextWatermark("Test watermark", new Font("Arial", 36));

// To make editing of the shape forbidden
CellsShapeSettings shapeSettings = new CellsShapeSettings();
shapeSettings.setLocked(true);

// Add watermark
doc.addModernWordArtWatermark(textWatermark, shapeSettings);

// Save document
doc.save("sample_watermarked.xlsx");
doc.close();
```

*Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.*